# What adjective would best describe adjectives that are related to feelings?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Joyful, happy, angry, hilarious, lovable, annoying, poignant, melancholic, depressing, cheerful, hateful, etc. All these ones are adjectives. Some of them can be applied to those objects who experience those feelings that these adjectives imply. Some of them can be applied to those objects that only cause those feelings in others. However, they are all related to feelings whether those are physical feelings (those that one's body can feel, like pain) or "soulish" feelings (those that are felt in one's soul, like liking or sympathy).

So, the question is how to name all these adjectives? Is there any term for such ones? (A term consisting of only one adjective is preferable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think *emotive* (or *emotional*) might fit the bill.

Comment: Yes Alex. I think that's the term I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*affective* – "relating to moods, feelings, and attitudes"